# When using Android sockets, why would a connection be "actively refused"?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I've copy/pasted the code from this [tutorial about sockets on Android](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/).

It builds fine and runs as expected, until a connection is attempted.

I've got it connected with USB and I've used ADB to turn on port forwarding.

I've written test apps in C# (which I'm more comfortable with than Java) and I keep getting [error 10061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAETIMEDOUT):

> No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running.

When I use [SocketTest](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/), I get the following (rather cryptic) message:

> Connection error: connect

I've tried disabling my firewall, but this doesn't help. What could be wrong?

Comment: "trying to connect to a service that is inactive"

Comment: Means that the target host is available, but there's no one listening on the port you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Use `nmap` on your development machine to check the status of the port. Or, try creating an app running inside of Android to check the port. Also, make sure that you are using a port number higher than 1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was to do with ADB. I had started port forwarding at the beginning of my session, but the ADB process must have restarted at some point because when I reissued the port forward command my app sprang to life.

Real pity there's no way of viewing the ports currently being forwarded by ADB. I suppose the bottom line is "if in doubt, do it again".

Answer (score 3):

"Actively refused" means that the target has send an packet back signaling that there is no process listening on the port ("no server application running"). Some firewalls even filter these packets, resulting in an timeout when there is an connection attempt.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what the error means, but as I'm already telling Android to start a new socket, I'm not sure why there isn't something listening on the port.